# Envers: error mapping a collection with deleted entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers, dozer

We are using Hibernate Envers to get the full data from an entity and its related entities in a certain date. And the problem is that we get an error when accessing items from a collection that were deleted after that moment.
So it seems the problem is because is accessing to DB to retrieve entities that doesn't exist anymore.

This is the main entity:

```
  @XmlType  
  @XmlRootElement  
  @Entity  
  @Audited  
  @Table(name = PayrollEntity.TABLE_NAME)  
  @NamedQueries({  
  @NamedQuery(name = PayrollEntity.EXISTS_BY_ID_QUERY_NAME, query = PayrollEntity.EXISTS_BY_ID_QUERY, hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}),  
  @NamedQuery(name = PayrollEntity.FIND_PAYROLL_QUERY_NAME, query = PayrollEntity.FIND_PAYROLL_QUERY, hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}),  
  @NamedQuery(name = PayrollEntity.FIND_EXTRAPAY_QUERY_NAME, query = PayrollEntity.FIND_EXTRAPAY_QUERY, hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}),  
  @NamedQuery(name = PayrollEntity.FIND_PAYROLLS_BY_EMPLOYMENT_QUERY_NAME, query = PayrollEntity.FIND_PAYROLLS_BY_EMPLOYMENT_QUERY, hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}),  
  })  
  public class PayrollEntity extends AbstractEntity {  

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1982937254314630067L;  

  /* PARAMS */  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_EXCLUDEDIDPAYROLL_PARAM = "idPayroll";  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDPAYROLLTYPE_PARAM = "idPayrollType";  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEMPLOYMENT_PARAM = "idEmployment";  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_YEAR_PARAM = "year";  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_MONTH_PARAM = "month";  
  public static final String EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEXTRAPAY_PARAM = "idExtraPay";  

  /* QUERIES */  
  public static final String EXISTS_BY_ID_QUERY_NAME = "EXISTS_PAYROLL_BY_ID";  
  public static final String EXISTS_BY_ID_QUERY =  
  "SELECT e.idPayroll FROM PayrollEntity e WHERE e.idPayroll = :" + EXISTS_BY_ID_QUERY_PARAM;  

  public static final String FIND_PAYROLL_QUERY_NAME = "EXISTS_PAYROLL_BY_CONCEPTUAL_ID";  
  public static final String FIND_PAYROLL_QUERY =  
  "SELECT e FROM PayrollEntity e WHERE e.idPayroll != :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_EXCLUDEDIDPAYROLL_PARAM  
  + " AND e.employment.idEmployment = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEMPLOYMENT_PARAM  
  + " AND e.year = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_YEAR_PARAM  
  + " AND e.month = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_MONTH_PARAM  
  + " AND e.payrollType.idPayrollType = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDPAYROLLTYPE_PARAM;  

  public static final String FIND_EXTRAPAY_QUERY_NAME = "EXISTS_EXTRAPAY_BY_CONCEPTUAL_ID";  
  public static final String FIND_EXTRAPAY_QUERY =  
  "SELECT e FROM PayrollEntity e WHERE e.idPayroll != :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_EXCLUDEDIDPAYROLL_PARAM  
  + " AND e.employment.idEmployment = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEMPLOYMENT_PARAM  
  + " AND e.year = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_YEAR_PARAM  
  + " AND e.month = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_MONTH_PARAM  
  + " AND e.payrollType.idPayrollType = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDPAYROLLTYPE_PARAM  
  + " AND e.extraPay.idExtraPay = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEXTRAPAY_PARAM;  

  public static final String FIND_PAYROLLS_BY_EMPLOYMENT_QUERY_NAME = "FIND_PAYROLLS_BY_EMPLOYMENT";  
  public static final String FIND_PAYROLLS_BY_EMPLOYMENT_QUERY =  
  "SELECT e FROM PayrollEntity e WHERE e.employment.idEmployment = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_IDEMPLOYMENT_PARAM  
  + " AND e.year = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_YEAR_PARAM  
  + " AND e.month = :" + EXISTS_PAYROLL_MONTH_PARAM;  

  /* TABLE */  
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "EP_PAYROLL";  

  /* COLUMNS */  
  public static final String ID_PAYROLL_COLUMN = "ID_PAYROLL";  
  public static final String VERSION_COLUMN = "VERSION";  
  public static final String ID_EMPLOYMENT_COLUMN = "ID_EMPLOYMENT";  
  public static final String ID_PAYROLL_TYPE_COLUMN = "ID_PAYROLL_TYPE";  
  public static final String YEAR_COLUMN = "YEAR";  
  public static final String MONTH_COLUMN = "MONTH";  
  public static final String CALCULATION_DATETIME_COLUMN = "CALCULATION_DATETIME";  
  public static final String PAYSLIP_GENERATION_DATETIME_COLUMN = "PAYSLIP_GENERATION_DATETIME";  
  public static final String ID_EXTRA_PAY_COLUMN = "ID_EXTRA_PAY";  
  public static final String DISCOUNT_RATE_CALCULATED = "DISCOUNT_RATE_CALCULATED";  
  public static final String DISCOUNT_RATE_SOLICITED = "DISCOUNT_RATE_SOLICITED";  
  public static final String DISCOUNT_RATE_APPLIED = "DISCOUNT_RATE_APPLIED";  

  private String idPayroll;  
  private int version;  
  private PayrollTypeEntity payrollType;  
  private EmploymentEntity employment;  
  private int year;  
  private int month;  
  private DateTime calculationDateTime;  
  private DateTime payslipGenerationDatetime;  
  private List<PayrollSalaryItemEntity> payrollSalaryItems;  
  private ExtraPayEntity extraPay;  
  private Float discountRateCalculated;  
  private Float discountRateSolicited;  
  private Float discountRateApplied;  

  @Column(name = CALCULATION_DATETIME_COLUMN)  
  @Type(type = JODA_DATE_TIME_JPA_CONVERTER)  
  public DateTime getCalculationDateTime() {  
  return calculationDateTime;  
  }  

  @Column(name = DISCOUNT_RATE_APPLIED, columnDefinition = "decimal(4,2)")  
  public Float getDiscountRateApplied() {  
  return discountRateApplied;  
  }  

  @Column(name = DISCOUNT_RATE_CALCULATED, columnDefinition = "decimal(4,2)")  
  public Float getDiscountRateCalculated() {  
  return discountRateCalculated;  
  }  

  @Column(name = DISCOUNT_RATE_SOLICITED, columnDefinition = "decimal(4,2)")  
  public Float getDiscountRateSolicited() {  
  return discountRateSolicited;  
  }  

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = EmploymentEntity.class)  
  @JoinColumn(name = ID_EMPLOYMENT_COLUMN, referencedColumnName = EmploymentEntity.ID_EMPLOYMENT_COLUMN)  
  public EmploymentEntity getEmployment() {  
  return employment;  
  }  

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ExtraPayEntity.class)  
  @JoinColumn(name = ID_EXTRA_PAY_COLUMN, referencedColumnName = ExtraPayEntity.ID_EXTRA_PAY_COLUMN)  
  public ExtraPayEntity getExtraPay() {  
  return extraPay;  
  }  

  @Column(name = ID_PAYROLL_COLUMN, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)  
  @Id  
  @GeneratedValue(generator = UUID_GENERATOR_NAME)  
  @GenericGenerator(name = UUID_GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = UUID_GENERATOR_STRATEGY)  
  public String getIdPayroll() {  
  return idPayroll;  
  }  

  @Column(name = MONTH_COLUMN)  
  public int getMonth() {  
  return month;  
  }  

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "payroll", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  
  public List<PayrollSalaryItemEntity> getPayrollSalaryItems() {  
  return payrollSalaryItems;  
  }  

  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)  
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PayrollTypeEntity.class)  
  @JoinColumn(name = ID_PAYROLL_TYPE_COLUMN, referencedColumnName = PayrollTypeEntity.ID_PAYROLL_TYPE_COLUMN)  
  public PayrollTypeEntity getPayrollType() {  
  return payrollType;  
  }  

  @Column(name = PAYSLIP_GENERATION_DATETIME_COLUMN)  
  @Type(type = JODA_DATE_TIME_JPA_CONVERTER)  
  public DateTime getPayslipGenerationDatetime() {  
  return payslipGenerationDatetime;  
  }  

  @Version  
  public int getVersion() {  
  return version;  
  }  

  @Column(name = YEAR_COLUMN)  
  public int getYear() {  
  return year;  
  }  

  public void setCalculationDateTime(DateTime calculationDate) {  
  this.calculationDateTime = calculationDate;  
  }  

  public void setDiscountRateApplied(Float discountRateApplied) {  
  this.discountRateApplied = discountRateApplied;  
  }  

  public void setDiscountRateCalculated(Float discountRateCalculated) {  
  this.discountRateCalculated = discountRateCalculated;  
  }  

  public void setDiscountRateSolicited(Float discountRateSolicited) {  
  this.discountRateSolicited = discountRateSolicited;  
  }  

  public void setEmployment(EmploymentEntity employment) {  
  this.employment = employment;  
  }  

  public void setExtraPay(ExtraPayEntity extraPay) {  
  this.extraPay = extraPay;  
  }  

  public void setIdPayroll(String idPayroll) {  
  this.idPayroll = idPayroll;  
  }  

  public void setMonth(int month) {  
  this.month = month;  
  }  

  public void setPayrollSalaryItems(List<PayrollSalaryItemEntity> payrollSalaryItems) {  
  this.payrollSalaryItems = payrollSalaryItems;  
  }  

  public void setPayrollType(PayrollTypeEntity payrollType) {  
  this.payrollType = payrollType;  
  }  

  public void setPayslipGenerationDatetime(DateTime payslipGenerationDatetime) {  
  this.payslipGenerationDatetime = payslipGenerationDatetime;  
  }  

  public void setVersion(int version) {  
  this.version = version;  
  }  

  public void setYear(int year) {  
  this.year = year;  
  }  
  }
```

This is the code we use to get the data from envers:

```
public PayrollEntity findHistorical(String idPayroll, DateTime date) {  
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(getEntityManager());  
return reader.find(PayrollEntity.class, idPayroll, (int)
    reader.createQuery()  
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(PayrollEntity.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("revTimestamp").lt(date.getMillis()))  
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().max())  
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(idPayroll))  
    .getSingleResult());  
    }
```

Then we try to map the data to a DTO using dozer, and we get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find es.gc.epsilon.core.domain.SalaryItemEntity with id 15  
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:157) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:262) [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176) [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]
```

As I said, it seems it's because dozer access to a deleted item from the payrollSalaryItems collection List from the main entity.

So, the question is. It's possible to map data from an entity containint deleted items in a collection to a DTO? Are we doing on the right way?

PD: we are using the Hibernate version 4.2.21.Final

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a problem identified both by [HHH-8093](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8093) and [HHH-8051](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8051), both of which are tentatively scheduled for Hibernate Envers 6.0 release.

If I get to these before the 6.0 release, I'll try.

Obviously that doesn't solve your immediate need on Hibernate Envers 4.2, which by the way is quite old and is no longer maintained or patched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @naros, I thought it was this bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5845 which is already fixed with the 4.2.21.Final version.

Is there any workaround we can try till you release the solution?